# how to chain View Property Animations

Tags: android, animation

I know how to use AnimatorSet to chain animations, ie.
play animation 1 -> play animation 2

but I don't know how to achieve this for ViewPropertyAnimator?
should I use "withEndAction" or should I use "setListener..onAnimationEnd" or something else?

thanks.
BR,
Henry

Answer (score 6):

`withEndAction()` should work, but is only available from API Level 16 onwards.

If you want something that works on older versions, including via the NineOldAndroids backport, use `setListener()` and `onAnimationEnd()`. Note that `AnimatorListenerAdapter` implements all of `AnimatorListener`'s methods, so you can extend `AnimatorListenerAdapter` and only override those methods that you need.